# Disable inheritance on a folder NTFS permissions in C#

Tags: c#, permissions, explorer

How can I disable inheritance on a folder and delete all inherited permissions

Thank you

I tried this :

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
dSecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, false);
```

Comment: Don't be a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).  Show us some research and what you've tried, and explain why it hasn't worked.  *Help us to help you.*

Comment: I tried this :
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
dSecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, false);

Comment: Don't put that in the comments -- update your question.  Also include how it didn't work.

Comment: So what's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: nothing append and I have no error, I don't think I have to use SetAccessRuleProtection but I don't find an other thing

Comment: Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem you're having. Please also provide a precise explanation of what that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Answer (score 13):

If someone search the solution :

```
        DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
        directorySecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, keepPermissions);
        Directory.SetAccessControl(path, directorySecurity);
```

with keepPermissions true if you want to keep inherited permissions.

Comment: Your questions says that you want to _"delete all inherited permissions"_. In what way does posting code that allows you to _"keep inherited permissions"_ qualify as an answer to the question you asked?

Comment: Because if someone want to keep permissions and juste delete inheritance, he has the answer too. Is it a problem ?

Comment: To save some other time, for those using .NET Standard 2.0, use DirectoryInfo.Get/SetAccessControl methods.