# Enable NTFS permissions inheritance in c#

Tags: c#, file-permissions, ntfs

I'm creating a new file and I want it to inherit the directory NTFS permissions (implicit permissions) but it's created with explicit permissions
I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34162619/1405268) question and tried:

```
var directorySecurity = System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl(Directory);
directorySecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, true);
System.IO.Directory.SetAccessControl(_fileName, directorySecurity);
```

Yet the file doesn't have enabled inheritance:
[image]

Comment: Can you include your code where you are creating the file?

Comment: Are you running as an Admin?  When running from Visual Studio you are not running as Admin unless you create a shortcut to VS and then right click shortcut ans select Run As Admin.

Comment: I'm not running as admin, yet, I'd expect permissions to get inherited

Comment: I can't share the code that creates the file, it's a native code of a dependency of my app